# I'm trying to move my 2D-array into a GridBagLayout

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, jframe, gridbaglayout

I'm working on a simple game and this 2D array is the map and will work as an hitbox. I want position level[0][0] to be in gridbag positon (0,0) and level[1][0] be in (0,1) and so forth. But, I can't get it to work and I don't understand why not.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;

public class TestSnaken {

    private JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TestSnaken window = new TestSnaken();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public TestSnaken() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 1024, 768);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0};
        gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0};
        gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(gridBagLayout);
        GridBagConstraints grid = new GridBagConstraints();

        int[][] level1 = {
            {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
            {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
            {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
            {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
            {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
            {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
            {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
            {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
            {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
            {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
            {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
            {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
            {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
            {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
            {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
            {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
            {1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
            {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
            {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
            {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
            {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
            {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
            {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
            {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
            {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
            {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
            {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
            {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
            {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}

        };
        //Here I'm trying to move the 2D-array into the GridBagLayout
        JLabel label;
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        for (int[] arr: level1) {
            grid.gridy = i;
            for (int elem: arr) {
                if(elem == 1){
                    label = new JLabel("x");
                }
                else {
                    label = new JLabel(" ");
                }
                grid.gridx = j;
                frame.getContentPane().add(label, grid);
                j++;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to signify that this is solved. You also get 2 reputation points for doing so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leave the gridBayLayout Parameters. I think you are using them wrong. And reset your j Variable to 0 before each run of your second for loop!

```
private void initialize() {
    [...]
    GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    //gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0};
    //gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0};
    //gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    //gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};

    [...]

    JLabel label;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for (int[] arr: level1) {
        grid.gridy = i;
        j = 0; // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        for (int elem: arr) {
            if(elem == 1){
                label = new JLabel("x");
            }
            else {
                label = new JLabel(" ");
            }
            grid.gridx = j;
            frame.getContentPane().add(label, grid);
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Then it is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

The way you iterate is error-prone as you have noticed. A simple `for` loop will be clearer:

```
for (int i = 0; i < level1.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < level1[0].length; j++) {
        grid.gridy = i;
        grid.gridx = j;
        if (level1[i][j] == 1) {
            label = new JLabel("x");
        }
        else {
            label = new JLabel(" ");
        }
        frame.getContentPane().add(label, grid);
    }
}
```

Also, the lines setting column and row widths and heights don't do anything in your code.

The following is after using `frame.pack()`. `setBounds` has the problem of not knowing what screen size you are going to run your code on.

[image]